# Android - SyncAdapter no sync anyway

Tags: android, synchronization

i've a problem with SyncAdapter, I implement it complety but only call to onPerfomSync() when I put extras with ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL otherwise don't sync, where could be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're triggering the SyncAdapter to start syncing each time?

Answer (score 0):

yes I have this code:

```
    btnTurnSync.setOnClickListener (new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(btnTurnSync.isChecked()){
                mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, Provider.AUTHORITY, true);
            }else    {
                mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, Provider.AUTHORITY, false);
            }
        }

    });


    btnSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED,true);
            mResolver.requestSync(mAccount, Provider.AUTHORITY, extras);
        }

    });
```

And not work, i check my manifiest and metadata files and looks fine everything

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I had the sync disabled in device, this only can activate from a widget that I had to add..

it is:

[image: widget]

my Android version is 2.3.1, seems that this version does have not a button to activate sync from the system settings

link from I found this solution: [solution link](http://www.montesinos.org.es/2013/07/sincronizacion-desactivada-en-android.html)